# How I get the value from different class

Tags: c#, unity

i get error , i cant get the value from different class..

```
public class First1 : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<IFirstListener> listeners = new List<IFirstListener>();
    public int watt;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D theCollider)
    {
        try {
            CharacterA characterA = theCollider.GetComponent<CharacterA>();
            this.watt += characterA.watt;
            for (int i = 0; i < listeners.Count; i++) {
                listeners[i].OnBaterryPluggedIn(this, characterA, characterA.watt);
            }
        }
        catch { /*On error do nothing*/ }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D theCollider) {
        try {
            CharacterA characterA = theCollider.GetComponent<CharacterA>();
            this.watt -= characterA.watt;
            if (characterA != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < listeners.Count; i++) {
                }
                    listeners[i].OnBaterryPluggedOut(this, characterA, characterA.watt);
            }
        }
        catch { /*On error do nothing*/ }
    }
```

i want to get the value var watt and assign to tott.. (tott = watt)

```
public class Second2 : MonoBehaviour {
    private List<ISecondListener> listeners = new List<ISecondListener>();
    public int tott;

    public void cek (){
        tott = watt; /* <--- how i can get the value from var watt at class First() to var tott?? */
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`watt` is an **instance variable** of class `First1`.

class `First1` is a `Monobehavior` so every "instance" of it must me attached to a `GameObject`.

The step in the order are:

1. Get a reference to the `GameObject` the specific instance you need of `First1` is attached to.
2. Get a reference to the `First1` component attached to the `GameObject`
3. Access the public field `watt`

It depends on how your scene is organized, a simple way of doing something like that:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Find("name of the GO where First1 component is attached");
First1 comp = go.GetComponent<First1>();
tott = comp.watt;
```